# System.Drawing.Color NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I just started getting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to set an a range with the Excel interop with the following code:

```
excelRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

I found that it is actually any color in the `System.Drawing.Color` class that has this problem. On a different server, the same code works just fine. I have tried removing the reference to `System.Drawing` and re-adding it but it did not fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: The right side of the assignment is not the problem.

Comment: The right side is absolutely the problem. Look at the immediate window, it is the System.Drawing.Color.Black object that has the null reference. I changed the code to excelRange.Interior.Color = 16777216; and it works just fine. I thought for sure it was something to do with the range as well but its not.

Comment: You may want to repair the .Net Framework.  `Color` is a struct, so it cannot be null.  `Color.R` is a byte, so it cannot be null.